# update method inside conditional statement Not updating data in the firebase database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I am working on my project with firebase database in nodejs.
when i am trying to update the data in the conditional statement then the update method
is not working but when i write the update method ouside the conditional statement then it is running                  successfully.I also used the async and await keyword but still not working. What to Do?
i used async and await keywords with the update method to get the promise.
I want to update in the firebase database on the basis of conditions so for that i need to use update                               method inside the conditions.

```
app.post("/TimeTable", async (req, res) => {
  const serial = await req.body.Serial;
  const subject = await req.body.Subject;
  const faculty = await req.body.Faculty;
  const timeslot = await req.body.value;
  const colDetails = `${subject} (${faculty});

  if (timeslot == "9:00AM-10:00AM") {
    // Perform the update operation
    return await update(ref(db, `/IoT-Dashboard/TimeTable/${serial}`), {
      Firstcol: colDetails,
    });
  } else if (timeslot == "10:00AM-11:00AM") {
    // Perform the update operation
    return await update(ref(db, `/IoT-Dashboard/TimeTable/${serial}`), {
      Secondcol: colDetails,
    });
  } else if (timeslot == "11:00AM-12:00PM") {
    // Perform the update operation
    return await update(ref(db, `/IoT-Dashboard/TimeTable/${serial}`), {
      Thirdcol: colDetails,
    });
  }
  // ...
  // Repeat the above else if blocks for other timeslots
  // ...

});
```

The above written code is not updating the properties in the firebase realtime database.

Any Solution?

Comment: It sounds like `timeslot` is not one of the values you're testing for. As I said in comment to your previous question about the same problem (going forward please don't post duplicates, but edit your original post), you'll have to debug that part yourself and tell us the result. For example, if you `console.log(timeslot);` right before the first `if`, what does it output?

Comment: the *timeslot* value is coming from the frontend to fetch it on the server and according to that *timeslot* i am doing manipulations

Comment: the `console.log(timeslot)`  gives me **9:00AM-10:00AM** when i click on the **9:00AM-10:00AM** timeslot on the frontend.

Comment: That's good to know. So the next step would be to check if the code goes into one of the `if` blocks and calls the Firestore API with the values you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your support.
I have solved the problem and now its updating the data successfully.

Comment: Good to hear you got it work @Yash!  --- What was the problem? Would it be worth posting that as an answer below, so that future visitors can benefit from it?